# How to create a SnowFlake query with parameters having single quotes?

Tags: python, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm generating a SnowFlake query that looks like this:

```
name_list = ("O'Reley", "de'Medici")
query = f'''
    SELECT *
    FROM "mydb"."myschema"."mytable" 
    WHERE NAME IN {name_list}
'''
```

How should I generate my `name_list` so that my SF query is

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "mydb"."myschema"."mytable" 
WHERE NAME IN ('O''Reley', 'de''Medici')
```

Comment: Your desired query has exactly what you want, so I don't understand what you are even asking.  Make it look like that.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Obligatory [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) warning! Please [bind your data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#binding-data) instead of using f-strings / string formatting.

Comment: @JohnGordon They're asking how to generate that desired query. I don't think Python has anything that will automatically double the nested quotes.

Comment: yeah. like @AbdulAzizBarkat said, use parameter binding. the only thing that should be in that array are an appropriate number of parameter markers. something like `"select * from table where name in {"?" + ",?" * (len(params)-1)}", and then pass the tuple of names that need to be escaped into the execute function.

Comment: Are you really asking "How can I convert `'` to `''` in a string"?

Comment: @MichaelSpeer You don't even need to match the number of items. As shown in the Snowflake docuumentation that Abdul linked to, it can do `IN (%s)` to bind a placeholder to a list.

Comment: @MichaelSpeer you don't need even that string interpolation the `pyformat` or `format` bindings support binding lists for the `IN` clause: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#pyformat-or-format-binding

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat nice. I've never used "snowflake". as far as I remember the databases I used didn't handle tuples/lists, but it's definitely a great feature if it's available.

Comment: @MichaelSpeer as far as I've seen most of the drivers / libraries to connect to databases I've used support this feature, I've never really used snowflake either 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [parameter binding](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#binding-data) rather than string formatting. This will take care of escaping special characters automatically.

```
name_list = ("O'Reley", "de'Medici")
query = '''
    SELECT *
    FROM "mydb"."myschema"."mytable" 
    WHERE NAME IN (%s)
'''
con.cursor.execute(query, [name_list])
```

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with SF string literals and how to escape quotes. Your answer works like a charm!!